# Take list of list as input in python

Tags: python, string, list

I need to take a input which will strictly be in the format `[[a,b], [c,d], ... ]`, that is a list containing multiple lists. All the inner list will be containing two integer items.

## Example:

`a = [[0, 4], [1, 2], [5, 7], [6, 7], [6, 9], [8, 10]]`

Problem is When I am passing this as an input it is bring converted to a string and then I am using this program to get the desired output but I am unable to make it work properly.

```
def l2l(li):
    li = li.split(',', ' ')
    out= []
    for i in li:
        try:
            int(i)
            out.append(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(out)
    out = list([out[i], out[i+1]] for i in range(0,len(out)-1,2))

    return out
```

## Input :

`a = [[0, 4], [1, 2], [5, 7], [6, 7], [6, 9], [8, 10]]`

## Output :

`[['0', '4'], ['1', '2'], ['5', '7'], ['6', '7'], ['6', '9'], ['8', '1']]`

Comment: Since that string happens to conform to the JSON format, you could use the module for that to parse the initial string. It should give you integers in the resulting object.

Comment: @Quroborus could you explain that?

Comment: @p.ram answered your question

Comment: Show the actual code where you call the function, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Python module `ast` to convert it to a literal.

```
import ast 

a = "[[0, 4], [1, 2], [5, 7], [6, 7], [6, 9], [8, 10]]"

lol = ast.literal_eval(a)

print("({}){}".format(type(lol), lol))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(<class 'list'>)[[0, 4], [1, 2], [5, 7], [6, 7], [6, 9], [8, 10]]
```

Comment: Actually, there is no need of the `ast` module. Try simply `eval(a)`. It still works.

Answer (score 0):

Use python's built in `eval` function:

```py
def l2l(li):
    li = eval(li)
    out= []
    for i in li:
        try:
            out.append(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(out)
    out = list([out[i], out[i+1]] for i in range(0,len(out)-1,2))

    return out
a = '[[0, 4], [1, 2], [5, 7], [6, 7], [6, 9], [8, 10]]'
l2l(a)
```

Out:

```
[[0, 4], [1, 2], [5, 7], [6, 7], [6, 9], [8, 10]]
```

Comment: `li = eval(li) is enough to for the required answers?

Comment: Just understand that eval can be dangerous.  it will on the fly evaluate whatever you pass it.  so if its something that runs code to erase a directory, etc. that would not be good for someone using your code.   I like the idea of using the json load string function better.